# How to pass current_user when creating new record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I need to pass `current_user` for `user_id` when creating `entity`. Its not working the way i'm doing it.

```
def create
    @entity = Entity.new(entity_params, :user_id = current_user)
    ...
end
```

In Schema I have `:user_id` as integer for `Entity` table. I also have `belongs_to :user` association in `models/entity.rb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` accepts a parameters hash, so it should work with:

```
@entity = Entity.new(entity_params.merge(user: current_user))
```

Another way would be

```
@entity = Entity.new(entity_params).tap do |entity|
  entity.user = current_user
end
```

Comment: How can I make sure `user_id` also passes to all associations below Entity when I'm making new Entity through complex form. Entity has many associations.

Answer (score 2):

A better way:

```
#app/controllers/entities_controller.rb
class EntitiesController < ApplicationController
   def create
     @entity = current_user.entities.new entity_params
     @entity.save
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
def create
  @entity = current_user.entities.create(entity_params)
end
```